# Is installing packages with python a possibility

Tags: python, linux, bash, redhat

I am an admin for multiple redhat systems, and I'm looking into possibly transitioning from bash scripts to python scripts, I just think bash looks really ugly and sometimes doing simple things in it is a hassle. Anyways, I was wondering if it was possible to do certain administrative things such as installing rpms, or something with a similar function to reposync & createrepo. If these things are not possible in python which I suspect from a quick google search, is it considered bad practice to use the os module to use bash commands where needed?

Comment: IMHO you'll need to run programs. But which bash commands would think are needed? What can the bash (on its own, not running programs) do, what Python can't do?

Comment: Well, like I was saying, in this specific example it would be "yum install example.rpm" At least from a quick google search I couldn't find a way to install packages using a python script. What do you mean by running programs? I would like to run a python script/program.

Comment: `yum` is a program. It's not a bash command. Other python libraries run programs as well. E.g. some PDF converters run Ghostscript.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you're saying, so I'm thinking about this wrong, all I need to do is have python call out to the yum program?

Comment: Yes, and that's what the `subprocess` library can do

Comment: How well do you actually know `bash`? The simple things usually aren't as hard as inexperienced shell coders think they are, from what I've seen.

Comment: Okay, that helps, thank you.

Comment: I would say I definitely know python better than bash, but I have a decent amount of experience with bash, used it a few times throughout college, and I've been working with it for about 6 months now. I don't necessarily think it's hard to do stuff in it, I just find myself looking commands up all the time for things like sed and awk with weird syntax, I also find that there's just some strange things with the language, for example, I don't make this mistake anymore but you can't use anything like ls/cd/pwd because those commands are based on where you are rather than where the script is.

Comment: I also don't like the syntax for if commands, again I look it up every time to make sure I'm doing it the right way, with strings you have to use "==", with numbers you use "-eq" feels very weird. As well as chaining commands together, it becomes a mess of $ and ().

Answer (score -1):

if you need to execute bash commands in python, beacuse for example you want to automate, you can use the os module:

```
import os
os.popen(<bash command>)
```

Comment: `os.popen` has been deprecated in favor of the `subprocess` module for over a decade.

Comment: It works well in python, python3 and weblogic scripting tool, which is commonly used in RHEL/Oracle servers. Subprocesses aren't supported in WLST.

Comment: I haven't used WLST, but subprocess has been included in python since 2.4 (2004).

Comment: he is a sysadmin as well as me, so i gave him the notation he could use in his env